# for some reason i keep getting 'app.get is not a function'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

this is my code:

```
const request = require('request');
const app = require('express');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

but for some reason i kepp getting this error :
"app.get is not a function"
I made sure that express is installed but it keeps throwing this error

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+express+get+is+not+a+function) of [TypeError: app.get is not a function](/q/40828932/4642212). Clearly documented in the [documentation](//expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html).

Comment: require('express')() will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must import express and call it like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express() // ->  (because it is function)
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

or,

```
const request = require('request');
const app = require('express')(); // -> immediate call
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I was about to delete this question because I just read the document but thank you for your help